# Bash prompt with zero width control characters

Tags: unicode, bashrc, control-characters

To prevent the prompt from warping around right-to-left text, I want to insert a zero width LRM into the bash prompt (U200e). Since this is a zero width character, my instinct was to wrap it with `\[<200e>\]`. Turns out, that actually causes bash to line wrap in the wrong place. When I don't wrap it with anything, *then* it seems to work fine.

Which I don't understand. Even if bash auto-detects this character is a zero width, wrapping a `\[...\]` around it shouldn't have hurt anything.

EDITED:
So the question is: when is `\[...\]` escaping actually needed, and how can it possibly be harmful if the chars it escapes are actually zero width.

Comment: Are you sure you did not add `\[` and `\]` inside an already existing `\[` `\]` pair? What is the output of `declare -p PS1`?

Comment: Quite sure. Just for test purpose, I declared a prompt where these are the only `\[\]` in the whole prompt. declare -p shows:
`declare -- PS1="Prompt\\[‎\\]\\\$ "`. Of course the zero width LRM doesn't show up, and may not have been copied, but it should be clear where it is. And, yes, the problem still happens.

Comment: I have copied the command from your comment and the character is there. `declare -p PS1` does not reveal it, but `declare -p PS1 | xxd` or even `echo "$PS1" | xxd` does.

Answer (score -1):

See the post
[Escaping zero length characters in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226139/escaping-zero-length-characters-in-bash).
and specifically the
[answer by Michael Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32267141/165358)
which I reproduce below:

> the `\[` sequences are used by some utilities, including PS1, to
> represent the `\001` and `\002` control codes:
>
> `\[` => `\x01` or `\001`
>
> `\]` => `\x02` or `\002`
>
> printf and echo don't do this translation from `\[` to `\001`.
>
> So the solution was to do the conversion myself. Instead of wrapping
> zero length characters in `\[`:
>
> ```
> echo "\[\033[1;30m\]foo\[\033[0m\]"
> ```
>
> which would output `\[foo\]`
>
> I instead output the actual control code:
>
> ```
> echo "\x01\033[1;30m\x02foo\x01\033[0m\x02"
> ```
>
> which outputs `foo` on both PS1 printf and echo.
>
> For a concrete example see [this commit on
> git-radar.](https://github.com/michaeldfallen/git-radar/commit/11e8ad4bdce9979eb871635bf455213788de5e05)

Comment: I fail to see how this answer explains the behavior observed by the OP. There is no explicit question in the "question". Maybe your answer answers some implicit question. If so, what question is it? If anything, I would interpret the OP's "which I don't understand" as a request for explanation, so I would expect answers to address this.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: This explains the difficulty of expressing such characters as prompt strings and offers a method.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: If you downvoted this one, it requires putting up an answer of your own.

Comment: I do not post answers when I know I don't know the answer.

Comment: I've edited the question so that what I'm actually asking is clearer.

Comment: Seems to me that by the above answer they are needed, and in addition they get mistranslated if put in the PS1 prompt string so that one needs to use `echo`/`printf`.

Comment: What I'm seeing is that what's true for ANSI color codes is not true for Unicode control characters, and I'm not sure why. Though I now have a suspicion which I wonder how to test.

Comment: Non-ansi multi-byte characters need to be issued one-byte at a time. To find out the bytes to issue, use for example `printf ☠ | hexdump`. For some solutions see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602912/how-do-you-echo-a-4-digit-unicode-character-in-bash). If this helps I can add it to my answer.